# Check whether a user is registered on skype or not

Tags: c#, skype

I am using Skype API to make a video call.Till now video call is working fine.I used an Xml file to save Skype credentials(which are used to call any other Skype friend/user). Before saving Skype credentials into Xml file I want to make sure that is the username provided are registered on Skype or not.

How to check whether a user is registered on Skype or not?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, at some point you're using the credentials to connect to Skype.

Simply don't save the credentials until you successfully connect.

(I hope by "credentials" you don't mean "plaintext username and password".)

Comment: this may me another option .Have you any better idea. :)

Comment: Well, if there's no built-in "check credentials" method in the API, you could try just logging in/doing something as the user and check if it's allowed.