# Check whether Skype Username and Password exist or not

Tags: c#, .net, skype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check whether a user is registered on skype or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028100/check-whether-a-user-is-registered-on-skype-or-not)

I am creating a .net Windows application and in this application i want to check whether the username and password entered by any user in my application realy exist or not . so have anybody any idea how should i do this?

thanks,

Answer (score -1):

It should not be that hard, you can use the skype API http://developer.skype.com/accessories/skype4com. Use this command to try to login to skype :

c:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\skype.exe /username:"stealthrt1992" /password:"mypasswordhere"

Just shell(cmd) it and then try to attach your application(that uses the API I gave you) to skype and then you ll be able to see or you are logged in or not.

Btw this is not a good idea if you want to brute force(since it will be too slow for that) but I don t think you are allowed to ask such things here anyway.

Comment: You should post this answer in the [duplicate thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028100/check-whether-a-user-is-registered-on-skype-or-not) as well

Comment: @Maximc let any user already have logged in on his mechine with some other skype credentials then?

Comment: Just do Shell("then the command and input the correct username and password"), then do a thread.sleep for like 5000 (5 sec, so skype can login if the info is correct ofc) then try to attach the application to skype, and check or you are logged in, I don t know the command by hard but it should be easy to find out.

Comment: That doesn t matter, since he wants either to know does the password and username match or not. He didn t wanted to know or the user existed, if so he can just use the api and search for contacts with it  for the usernames he wants to check.

Comment: @Ramhound, but as I said in my last comment, he can login with his own skype account, then use the API to let his application attach to skype, and then use the APi search for contacts, if the username exists, then he should try to login, if it fails, then he know the pw is bad, if the user was not found then the username doesn t exist.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18468/discussion-between-ramhound-and-maximc)